# Proposition avec "si" et "devoir" au conditionnel pour suggérer quelque chose

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, subordonnées, conditionnel, conditions

J'ai envie de dire "Si tu as du temps libre, on devrait se parler !" (en anglais: "If you have some free time, we should talk!") à une amie avec qui ça fait longtemps qu'on ne s'est pas parlé, donc je veux lui proposer qu'on se parle encore. Du coup, je fais une suggestion qui va probablement se réaliser.

Cependant, on m'a appris qu'il existe plusieurs façons de formuler des propositions avec "si" :

1. **le présent + le présent** : Si tu es fatigué, je peux conduire la voiture.
2. **le présent + le futur** : Si tu es fatigué, je te lirai une histoire du soir.
3. **le présent + l'impératif** : Si tu es fatigué, couche-toi.
4. **le passé composé + le présent/futur/impératif** : Si tu as travaillé toute la journée, il vaut mieux que tu te couches.
5. **l'imparfait + le conditionnel** : Si tu étais fatigué, tu pourrais te coucher.
6. **le "pluperfect" + le "conditional perfect"** (je ne sais pas comment s'appellent ces temps en français) : Si tu avais travaillé toute la journée, je t'aurais permis de te coucher.

Le cinquième cas est le plus proche de ce que je veux dire, sauf que cette formulation exprime quelque chose qui est contraire à la réalité ou qui est improbable de se réaliser.

Donc, comment peut-on dire une telle chose en français — faire une suggestion qui dépend de la réalité ? Est-ce que j'ai eu raison avec ma tentative ci-dessus ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le problème avec *Si tu as du temps libre, on devrait se parler !* n'est pas le conditionnel (quelque chose comme *Si tu es libre ce midi, on pourrait déjeuner ensemble* est naturel bien qu'un peu formel) c'est qu'il donne l'impression que le fait de se parler est une conséquence naturelle très probable et pas le résultat d'un choix (P.e. je peux dire a un collègue qui travaille sur un autre site *Si tu es au bureau demain, on devrait se voir.* si je me rends sur ce site le lendemain et que donc il est probable qu'on se rencontre).

Quant à l'origine de la question, *si tu as du temps libre, il faut qu'on cause, qu'on aille boire un verre, qu'on se fasse une bouffe* est plus proche de ce que je dirai à un ami.

Comment: Il me semble que je ne suis pas certain de tous les sens que *falloir* et *devoir* peuvent avoir. *Si tu es au bureau demain, on devrait se voir* est equivalent à *si tu es au bureau demain, on se verra*, non ? Je pensais que *devoir* aurait convenu mieux (à ma phrase) parce que ça suggère que j'aimerais bien se parler (et que je m'attends même que mon amie se sent pareil), pendant que je reconnais en même temps qu'il ne pourrait pas être possible si l'autre n'avait pas de temps libre. C'est un choix, mais un choix où une option est plus probable que l'autre.

Comment: De plus, *Falloir* donnerait un sens d'urgence ou de nécessité, non ?

Comment: @bronxbomber92, c'est moins certain. _On se verra_ est plus certain, ça donne l'impression qu'on va chercher à se voir, tandis qu'_on devrait se voir_ donne plutôt l'impression qu'on va nécessairement se croiser même sans chercher à le faire.  Quant aux nuances entre falloir et devoir, j'aurais du mal à les expliquer en dehors d'exemples sans me baser sur une référence ayant déà fait l'analyse.

Answer (score 2):

« Si tu as du temps libre, on devrait se parler !» est grammaticalement correct, mais l'emploi de *devoir* provoque ici une impression un peu étrange... En effet, « si tu as du temps libre » donne l'impression qu'on va proposer quelque chose qui n'est pas primordial, en contradiction avec le sens impératif de « devoir ».

Donc, si il est très important de parler avec le personne (mais qu'on souhaite attendre le bon moment), j'emploierai plutôt « Lorsque tu auras du temps libre, nous devrons nous parler !».

Si, à l'inverse, il s'agit de proposer une discussion informelle si la personne n'a rien d'autre à faire, j'emploierai *pouvoir* à la place de devoir : « Si tu as du temps libre (si tu es disponible), nous pourrions nous parler (discuter) ». Pouvoir me semble d'ailleurs plus proche de *should*, tandis que devoir correspondrait plutôt à *must*.

Comment: Je ne suis absolument pas d'accord avec *devrons*. Ça me semble très peu idiomatique et je ne peux pas imaginer de situation ou je dirais ça (le *nous* n'aide pas non plus). Pour le cas dont tu parles, c'est *falloir* que j'emploierais: *il faudra/va falloir qu'on se parle*.

Comment: C'est certainement un peu formel... Mais certaines situation graves peuvent s'y prêter. par exemple « Lorsque tu auras du temps, nous devrons parler sérieusement de l'avenir de notre relation. »

Comment: J'apprécie ton réponse et ta suggestion ! Merci !